# How to build cloud functions which are part of a golang monorepo using gcloud cli?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

Lets say you have a mono repo with a structure similar to this:

```
my-app/
├─ api/
├─ ├─ api.go
├─ shared/
│  ├─ shared.go
├─ function/
│  ├─ function.go
├─ go.mod
```

If I only want to build `function.go` how can I achieve this using `gcloud function deploy`? The `--source` parameter doesn't work in this case as it will only load and compile the code in the `/function` directory, missing the required `/shared` dependencies (not available publicly). I really want to avoid creating a vendor directory.

Comment: You can do that with the raw CLI. You have to move/copy part of your code and then deploy. Monorepo often requires CI/CD to correctly package the code before deployment.